# Find end date of quarter given date, pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Assume we have a table like

```
table = [[datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1), 1, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 27), 1, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 31), 1, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 1), 1, 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 3), 1, 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 15), 1, 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 28), 1, 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1), 1, 3],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 17), 1, 3],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31), 1, 3]]

df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['Date', 'Id', 'Value'])
```

Is there a way to get the specific end date of the *actual* quarter given the dates in the column `Date`? E.g., I would like to add the column `Q_date` to `df` such that

```
        Date  Id  Value  Qdate
0 2015-01-01   1    0.5  2015-03-31
1 2015-01-27   1    0.5  2015-03-31
2 2015-01-31   1    0.5  2015-03-31
3 2015-02-01   1    2.0  2015-03-31
4 2015-02-03   1    2.0  2015-03-31
5 2015-02-15   1    2.0  2015-03-31
6 2015-02-28   1    2.0  2015-03-31
7 2015-03-01   1    3.0  2015-03-31
8 2015-03-17   1    3.0  2015-03-31
9 2015-03-31   1    3.0  2015-03-31
```

I've only considered the first quarter for simplicity - as I know what date it is.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd()` to achieve your goal here.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# your data
# ================================
table = [[datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1), 1, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 27), 1, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 31), 1, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 1), 1, 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 3), 1, 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 15), 1, 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 28), 1, 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1), 1, 3],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 17), 1, 3],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31), 1, 3]]

df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['Date', 'Id', 'Value'])

# processing
# ================================
# in case of 2015.03.31, simple QuarterEnd will roll forward to next quarter, so use DateOffset here to make it robust to this
df['Qdate'] = [date - pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(days=1) + pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd() for date in  df.Date]

print(df)


        Date  Id  Value      Qdate
0 2015-01-01   1    0.5 2015-03-31
1 2015-01-27   1    0.5 2015-03-31
2 2015-01-31   1    0.5 2015-03-31
3 2015-02-01   1    2.0 2015-03-31
4 2015-02-03   1    2.0 2015-03-31
5 2015-02-15   1    2.0 2015-03-31
6 2015-02-28   1    2.0 2015-03-31
7 2015-03-01   1    3.0 2015-03-31
8 2015-03-17   1    3.0 2015-03-31
9 2015-03-31   1    3.0 2015-03-31
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much (again)! Your solutions are always awesome and elegant. I'll mark it as answered in exactly 7 minutes...

Comment: Just to make this answer a little more elegant, you can use: `date + pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd(n=0)`

Comment: Fantastic! You just saved my life.

Answer (score 18):

An easier way to do it would be to convert the date to a (quarter) period, and then back to a date, e.g.:

```
df['Qdate'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period("Q").dt.end_time
```

Note there is also `.start_time` for the start of the quarter.

Comment: Yes, cleaner and more robust answer.

Answer (score 4):

Using [searchsorted](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) is another option:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

table = [[datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1), 1, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 27), 1, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 31), 1, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 1), 1, 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 3), 1, 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 15), 1, 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 28), 1, 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1), 1, 3],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 17), 1, 3],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31), 1, 3],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1), 1, 3],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['Date', 'Id', 'Value'])
quarters = pd.date_range(
    df['Date'].min(), 
    df['Date'].max()+pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd(), freq='Q')
df['Qdate'] = quarters[quarters.searchsorted(df['Date'].values)]
print(df)
```

yields

```
         Date  Id  Value      Qdate
0  2015-01-01   1    0.5 2015-03-31
1  2015-01-27   1    0.5 2015-03-31
2  2015-01-31   1    0.5 2015-03-31
3  2015-02-01   1    2.0 2015-03-31
4  2015-02-03   1    2.0 2015-03-31
5  2015-02-15   1    2.0 2015-03-31
6  2015-02-28   1    2.0 2015-03-31
7  2015-03-01   1    3.0 2015-03-31
8  2015-03-17   1    3.0 2015-03-31
9  2015-03-31   1    3.0 2015-03-31
10 2015-04-01   1    3.0 2015-06-30
```

By avoiding computation row-by-row, using searchsorted as above can be orders of magnitude faster for moderately large DataFrames.

Comment: This is actually something I contemplated myself - i.e. to generate a `date_range` list and find the quarters. So thank you very much!

Comment: This is significantly faster than the accepted approach for a large data frame.

Answer (score 2):

Really great @Jianxun! Here is an alternative approach:

```
import calendar

def f(x):
    q = ((x[0].month-1)//3 + 1)*3
    last = calendar.monthrange(x[0].year,q)[1]
    return datetime.date(x[0].year, q, last)

df['QDate'] = df.apply(f,axis=1)


In [24]: df
Out[24]:
        Date  Id  Value       QDate
0 2015-01-01   1    0.5  2015-03-31
1 2015-01-27   1    0.5  2015-03-31
2 2015-01-31   1    0.5  2015-03-31
3 2015-02-01   1    2.0  2015-03-31
4 2015-02-03   1    2.0  2015-03-31
5 2015-02-15   1    2.0  2015-03-31
6 2015-02-28   1    2.0  2015-03-31
7 2015-03-01   1    3.0  2015-03-31
8 2015-03-17   1    3.0  2015-03-31
9 2015-03-31   1    3.0  2015-03-31
```